# How to use dynamic information on config.xml?

Tags: xml, magento, magento-1.7

I need to use some dynamic information from "system.xml" on my 'config.xml'.

How i do that??

Something like this:(system.xml)

```
                    <title translate="label">
                        <label>Title</label>
                        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>15</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </title>
```

And on my config i'll use that information setted up by customer(user) to do something else.

Its possible?

Answer (score 2):

system file can have dynamic content

Steps :

Declare a field as follows :

```
<label>
    <model>module/adminhtml_label</model>
</label>
```

Then you need to create a model i.e module/adminhtml_label with content

```
class Namespace_Module_Model_Adminhtml_Label{
    public function getLabelText(){ //this method returns the text for the label
        return "Some text here";
    }
}
```

So your final system.xml will be something like :

```
<title translate="label">
    <label>
        <model>module/adminhtml_label</model>
    </label>
    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
    <sort_order>15</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</title>
```

Hope this helps you in some way.

Comment: Thanks for you time and answer, but i need to that on "config.xml" with system.xml data. So on my config.xml i'll have a node who will have the information setted on system.xml.